# Index type for user-defined containers

Tags: c++

I'm writing a matrix class in C++; which type should I use for indices into the matrix? That is, in the following code:

```
template <class elem_type>
class matrix
{
public:
  // snip
  elem_type const &operator()(INDEX_TYPE row, INDEX_TYPE column) const;
};
```

what should INDEX_TYPE be? If the matrix is restricted to small sizes, should I use a potentially smaller integral type?

Comment: try `unsigned int` or `int`

Comment: INDEX_TYPE shoud be `unsigned int` . Using `signed int` allows the user to use `my_matrix(-1, 3)` which doesn't mean anything in maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type should be unsigned and integer as an index (It's not a general advice). So [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) which is compatible with standard types, is suitable.

> std::size_t can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array).
>
> std::size_t is commonly used for array indexing and loop counting.

Small size types have no major benefits for you. Do you have memory limitations? I don't think so.